# Search function in a VB.Net windows form using sqlite

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite, search

I've been having some trouble trying to get this to work, I am trying to enter a code in the top bar, press 'Go' and it show up in the ListBox on the left. I hope one of you can help me with this, I have attached the code below for entering data from the table 'stock' from my database into the list box, however I'm stuck with narrowing it down with a search function. I have also attached an image of my form.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD9EZ.png

```
    Private Sub LoadStockFromDb()
    Dim stockInfo As DataRow = Nothing
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM stock;"

    Try
        Dim current_index As Int16 = lb_stock.SelectedIndex
        Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString.ToString)
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(conn)
                cmd.CommandText = sql
                conn.Open()
                Using da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    da.Fill(dt)

                    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        lb_stock.DisplayMember = "int_code"
                        lb_stock.ValueMember = "entry_id"
                        lb_stock.DataSource = dt
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        If current_index > 0 Then
            lb_stock.SelectedIndex = current_index
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: So, you've given us how you're loading the data into a datatable, I'm guessing you want some help with the go button click event?  How bout showing us what you've got there so far

Comment: Why do you want the user to type into the text box? Can't he just select a code from the list box?